# Spring websocket connection not being established

Tags: java, spring

I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) to build a spring websocket application. I've kept each file as it is but I'm neither using maven nor gradle. I run the index.html file on the tomcat server. When I click connect I get:

> Opening Web Socket...  GET http://localhost:8080/hello/info 404 (Not
>   Found)  Whoops! Lost connection to undefined

in my Chrome's Developer window. 
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593543/how-to-send-notification-to-php-webpage-from-spring-rest-api) may help. here I have given whole example.

for this you will require stomp.js, sockjs on your client side
and spring-websocket & spring-messaging 4.2.6.RELEASE jar in your server side,

Comment: I've added the start.jsp(client side code), sockjs & stompjs in WebContent folder of my project. And the spring jars(v. 4.2.0) are added into server. Still it's giving this error

Comment: find my project on (https://github.com/cz-colin/spring-web-socket-demo/tree/master) . I have created  spring websocket application with rest. hope it may help your problem.